# Can a continuous C# WebJob automatically handle difference message types in a single ServiceBus queue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have created an Azure WebJob to handle **two** different custom messages in a **single** ServiceBus queue.

Is this supported by the automagic deserialisation?

i.e. can I just create two functions, each with the same `ServiceBusTrigger` but a different message parameter:

```
public static void ProcessMessageA([ServiceBusTrigger("MessageQueue")] MessageA message) { ... }
public static void ProcessMessageB([ServiceBusTrigger("MessageQueue")] MessageB message) { ... }
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work, so do I have to handle `BrokeredMessage` and manually deserialise and handle the messages as appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the webjob SDK has no idea which message is of type A or B.

So as you said you have the option to de-serialize manually the brokered message. I think you should add a property on your brokered message to specify the type of the message.

So to send a message it could be something like that:

```
// Create the object you want to send
var messageA = new MessageA();
... 

// Create the borkered message
var message = new BrokeredMessage(messageA);

// Add a property 
message.Properties["messageType"] = "MessageA";

// Send the message
...
```

So now you only have one function in your webjob

```
public static void ProcessMessageA([ServiceBusTrigger("MessageQueue")] BrokeredMessage message)
{
    var messageType = (string) message.Properties["messageType"];
    if (messageType == "MessageA")
    {
        // Deserialize the message
        var messageA = message.GetBody<MessageA>();
        // Process the message
    }
    else if (messageType == "MessageB")
    {
        // Deserialize the message
        var messageB = message.GetBody<MessageB>();;
        // Process the message
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can create separate queues for each type of message
Or create a [service bus topic](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/) with two subscriptions.

While creating a subscription, you can specify a filter.

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

// Create the topic
namespaceManager.CreateTopic("TestTopic");

// Create subscription to handle message A
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("TestTopic", "MessageA", new SqlFilter("messageType = 'MessageA'"));
// Create subscription to handle message A
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("TestTopic", "MessageB", new SqlFilter("messageType = 'MessageB'"));
```

So now you can have two different functions in your webjob to handle MessageA and  MessageB.

```
public static void ProcessMessageA([ServiceBusTrigger("TestTopic", "MessageA")] MessageA message) { }

public static void ProcessMessageB([ServiceBusTrigger("TestTopic", "MessageB")] MessageB message) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add a datacontract attribute to your class definition, something like:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "JobTransactionTopic.Notification")]
public class Notification
{
    #region Public Properties

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int LoginId { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

If your two classes are different, then maybe the serializer will be able to distinguish between them. It is important that the sender and the receiver share the same namespace and that the class definition will be the same in both sides.

Let us know if it helps, I'm curious about it.